# Wrong data type in pointer declaration

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

In the below program, I would expect only first one byte of variable `i` to be read by pointer `j`. But it is giving a huge value as output. Please let me know your views.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 2147483647;
    char *j;
    j = &i;
    printf("Value of i = %u\n", *j);
    printf("Max value of INT = %d\n", INT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Value of i = 4294967295 Max value of INT = 2147483647

Comment: 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF) , `*j` = 0xFF(-1) (Little-Endian), `-1` ==> unsigned (32bit) ==> 4294967295

Comment: This is due to `char` implementation being `signed char`. So, to make it work as you would expect, like `printf("Value of i = %u\n",(unsigned char)*j);`.

Comment: In other environments, `char` may be implemented in `unsigned char`.

Comment: Don't use citation marks if you don't cite.

Comment: @Stargateur: It is not a citation and should be fromated like console-output which it is.

Comment: @Olaf console-output is not code... The only thing that I found is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190092/should-console-output-be-formatted-as-code-sample-or-as-blockquote). The only reason to use code format is to keep space and new line. But in this case, there is not point. Give me a proof that your rule is true.

Comment: Isn't it UB to use the wrong type of argument with a specifier?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY -- Thanks a lot for clarifying my doubt!

Comment: @Stargateur So what if there was more than one line on the console? However, it is not that important to me as it seem to be for you. I'll leave it as is, you can put it under a tree. Merry christmas!

Answer (score 1):

The first byte happens to have the representation of bits, that when interpreted as a value of type char, will yield a small negative value. This type is then promoted to type int when it is passed to printf. Then printf reinterprets the bits of the passed variable of type int, as type unsigned int. Those bits happens to represent a large value.

Type char is printed with the specifier `c`.

However you're trying to print a byte, not a printable character, so you should use the type unsigned char and the specifier `hhu`.

Answer (score -1):

You are displaying i as Unsigned integer so that it will consider variable 'i' as a large value. You should use external type casting while displaying the i value as (char)*J

Comment: `*j` (lowercase!) **is** `char`, so why the cast? And OP does not print `i`.